# What is Bank Label in Win32_PhysicalMemory class

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, ram, wmi-query

I am using 'ObjectQuery' in C# to get the Total RAM installed on the system. I am capturing the 'Capacity' from 'Win32_PhysicalMemory' object.
Following is the code:

```
double totalCapacity = 0;
ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection vals = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject val in vals)
{
    totalCapacity += System.Convert.ToDouble(val.GetPropertyValue("Capacity"));
}
double ramCapacity = totalCapacity / 1048576;
return ramCapacity.ToString();
```

It is working well on most the systems. But there are a few systems where the Installed RAM is 1 GB but is being grabbed as 512 MB by the code. *(**edit:** It is a single RAM stick of 1 GB)*

I also checked the 'BankLabel' variable in the 'Win32_PhysicalMemory' object on those systems. It was as follows 'Bank0/1'.
Now as far as I understand I guess the 1 GB memory has been divided into two banks of 512 - 512 MB each and those are switched.

1. Now the Question is, is my understanding right about the memory being divided into two bank hence shown as 512 MB each.
2. Also is it possible that a memory will be divided into two unequal banks like 3 GB divided into 1 GB and 2 GB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real sure about the answers to your questions, but I think I have a solution to your problem. Try this instead:

```
ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
```

and

```
val.GetPropertyValue("TotalPhysicalMemory")
```

That will get you the amount of RAM in bytes. You'll have to convert it to get MiBs or GiBs.

On the other hand, if you're trying to determine what RAM is in a system as opposed to how much RAM is in a system, then crack one open and see if there are multiple sticks in it. That will answer your questions pretty quick.

Comment: Yes, I had checked forgot to mention it, it is a single RAM stick of 1GB(getting it as 512 MB). I want to determine the same installed programatically.
Also the 'TotalPhysicalMemory' attribute in 'Win32_ComputerSystem' gives the 'RAM' as 3386 MBs on the 4GB system. 'Capacity' in 'Win32_PhysicalMemory' gives 4096 MBs which is proper.

Comment: @SaurabhHarwande Gotta give you props. I was not aware that TotalPhysicalMemory does NOT count memory used by the BIOS for other hardware (shared video memory for example). [This link](http://briandesmond.com/blog/getting-total-installed-memory-with-wmi/) and [this link](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_memory.htm) explain it more.